# how to test bluetoothchat application

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation

I want to run bluetooth chat application(sample code given on http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html)
But i cant test it on emulator. i have smartphone(android 2.3) but action bar given in that code supports API level only above 11.
atleast on emulator activity should start but it is giving me

FATAL EXCEPTIONS
Runtime error

so what should i do..?

plzz help

thnxxx

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth is not supported by emulator you have to check Bluetooth apps on real devices

paste your error

check its manifest file minsdk is 6

```
<uses-sdk minSdkVersion="6" />
```

so it will run on device below api 11

Adding the Action Bar

Beginning with Android 3.0 (API level 11), the action bar is included in all activities that use the Theme.Holo theme (or one of its descendants), which is the default theme when either the targetSdkVersion or minSdkVersion attribute is set to "11" or greater. For example:

```
<manifest ... >
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4"
              android:targetSdkVersion="11" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

In this example, the application requires a minimum version of API Level 4 (Android 1.6), but it also targets API level 11 (Android 3.0). This way, when the application runs on Android 3.0 or greater, the system applies the holographic theme to each activity, and thus, each activity includes the action bar.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

go to this path on your comp if you have installed sample apps through sdk manager

```
C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk-windows\samples\android-8\BluetoothChat
```

Comment: but in sample code they have used action bar which is supported only above API level 11.

Comment: tell me how to replace that action bar

Comment: Cant we use anything else in place of Action bar n if yes thn how in case of bluetoothchat application...

Comment: also can we use action bar at lower level of API's n how..?

Comment: i have already mentioned about backward compatibility
just read that page.